# How To allow MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission by programmatically in react native (android 11 or above)

Tags: android, react-native

[Error: sdcard/1f00e343-f4d0-448d-a268-45484390fb09.mp3: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)]

Comment: If you have any questions then please put them in your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.